# Why Unrolled LinkedList is semi filled?

Tags: data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

Going through all the articles related to the implementation of Unrolled LinkedList, it seems that based on the capacity we generate a threshold and if the elements increase beyond that we create another node and put the element in that node.

> Threshold = (capacity/2)+1

But why are we not filling the array in Unrolled LinkedList to its full capacity and then creating another node? Why do we need a threshold and keep the array semi-filled?

Quoted from [Geeks for Geeks - insertion in Unrolled Linked List](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/insertion-unrolled-linked-list/):

```java
/* Java program to show the insertion operation
* of Unrolled Linked List */
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
 
// class for each node
class UnrollNode {
    UnrollNode next;
    int num_elements;
    int array[];
 
    // Constructor
    public UnrollNode(int n)
    {
        next = null;
        num_elements = 0;
        array = new int[n];
    }
}
 
// Operation of Unrolled Function
class UnrollLinkList {
 
    private UnrollNode start_pos;
    private UnrollNode end_pos;
 
    int size_node;
    int nNode;
 
    // Parameterized Constructor
    UnrollLinkList(int capacity)
    {
        start_pos = null;
        end_pos = null;
        nNode = 0;
        size_node = capacity + 1;
    }
 
    // Insertion operation
    void Insert(int num)
    {
        nNode++;
 
        // Check if the list starts from NULL
        if (start_pos == null) {
            start_pos = new UnrollNode(size_node);
            start_pos.array[0] = num;
            start_pos.num_elements++;
            end_pos = start_pos;
            return;
        }
 
        // Attaching the elements into nodes
        if (end_pos.num_elements + 1 < size_node) {
            end_pos.array[end_pos.num_elements] = num;
            end_pos.num_elements++;
        }
 
        // Creation of new Node
        else {
            UnrollNode node_pointer = new UnrollNode(size_node);
            int j = 0;
            for (int i = end_pos.num_elements / 2 + 1;
                 i < end_pos.num_elements; i++)
                node_pointer.array[j++] = end_pos.array[i];
 
            node_pointer.array[j++] = num;
            node_pointer.num_elements = j;
            end_pos.num_elements = end_pos.num_elements / 2 + 1;
            end_pos.next = node_pointer;
            end_pos = node_pointer;
        }
    }
 
    // Display the Linked List
    void display()
    {
        System.out.print("\nUnrolled Linked List = ");
        System.out.println();
        UnrollNode pointer = start_pos;
        while (pointer != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < pointer.num_elements; i++)
                System.out.print(pointer.array[i] + " ");
            System.out.println();
            pointer = pointer.next;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
 
/* Main Class */
class UnrolledLinkedList_Check {
 
    // Driver code
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
 
        // create instance of Random class
        Random rand = new Random();
 
        UnrollLinkList ull = new UnrollLinkList(5);
 
        // Perform Insertion Operation
        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
 
            // Generate random integers in range 0 to 99
            int rand_int1 = rand.nextInt(100);
            System.out.println("Entered Element is " + rand_int1);
            ull.Insert(rand_int1);
            ull.display();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Their implementation looks like it's actually for `append` rather than `insert`. If they had implemented `insert` correctly, it'd have further arguments for where to insert. Then the empty space would make sense.

Answer (score 0):

> why are we not filling the array in Unrolled LinkedList to its full capacity and then creating another node?

Actually, the code that is provided *does* fill the array to full capacity:

```java
if (end_pos.num_elements + 1 < size_node) {
    end_pos.array[end_pos.num_elements] = num;
    end_pos.num_elements++;
}
```

The threshold is not used here. Only when the array reaches its capacity, the threshold plays a role as a new array gets created:

```java
UnrollNode node_pointer = new UnrollNode(size_node);
int j = 0;
for (int i = end_pos.num_elements / 2 + 1; i < end_pos.num_elements; i++)
    node_pointer.array[j++] = end_pos.array[i];
```

Here we see the second half of the full array is copied into the new array. We can imagine this process as splitting a block into two blocks -- much like happens in a B-tree.

This allows for fast insertion the next time a value needs to be *inserted* (not at the end, but) at a specific offset in *that* array. If it were left full, it would trigger a new block at each insertion into that array. By leaving slack space in an array, we ensure fast insertion for at least a few of the future insertions that happen to be in that array.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is to ensure having at least 50% utilization.

The algorithm not only splits in half if an insert is done, but also redistributes content if it's utilized at less than 50%. I think the second part is key: if you don't do the first part, you can't add a check that redistributes if the node is underutilized because your newly created node would immediately break that.

If you don't do the redistribution at all you might end up with a situation where you have a lot of underutilized nodes.

My first intuition was the same as the other comment (to avoid creating new nodes every time) but this wouldn't necessarily be an issue if you always check the next node before creating a new node, so I'm not sure that sufficient as a reason? (But maybe I'm missing something here)